# Spring Retryable not work for propagation=Required

Tags: spring, spring-retry

@Retryable works in my case only for

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Retryable(value = StaleStateException.class)
```

but not for

```
@Transactional
@Retryable(value = StaleStateException.class)
```

This is my code:

```
   @Log4j2
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServiceA {

  private final CounterService counterService ;

  @Transactional
  public void doJob(String counterType) {
    counterService.getNextValueCounter(counterType);
    
    // do some more jobs
    // can RuntimeException occur
    }
}

@Log4j2
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CounterService {

  private final CounterRepository counterRepository;

  @Transactional
  @Retryable(value = StaleStateException.class)
  public Long getNextCounterValue(String counterType) {
    Optional<Counter> counterOptional = counterRepository.findById(counterType);
    if (counterOptional.isPresent()) {
      Counter counter = counterOptional.get();
      if (counter.get().getMaxVersion() != null) {
        counter.setMaxVersion(counter.getMaxVersion() + 1);
        return counter.getMaxVersion();
      } else {
        counter.setMaxVersion(1L);
        return 1L;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}

public interface CounterRepository extends JpaRepository<Counter, String> {

  @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)
  Optional<Counter> findById(String id);
}
```

I would like to have default propagation because I would like to rollback counter when exception occurs in ServiceA. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? If you use the default propagation, the counter will be incremented for each retry (if `doJob()` is successful) or rolled back if not.

Comment: It means that after first try with StaleStateException exception in getNextCounterValue() my transaction is marked as "for rollback", even if second retry is successful.

Comment: Since you are already in a transaction from the calling method, you don't need the `@Transactional` on the retryable method, if you want default propagation; just remove it.

Comment: Yes, but it will be the same because by default propagation is REQUIRED which means that it supports a current transaction if exists.

Comment: I understand that, but that's just the way the interceptor is designed; any `@Transational` method using the existing transaction that throws an exception will cause a rollback of the entire transaction. Just leave it off to get the behavior you want. If you want to start a new transaction if one doesn't exist, you'll need to change your design to add another "wrapper" `@Transactional` method.